# Electrolysis of aluminum in a solution of magnesium sulfate

Tags: electrolysis

So I recently started looking into electrolysis to produce chemicals and I have only produced a few chemicals from it like copper hydroxide and copper sulfate. However I can’t seem to figure out what this wight precipitate that is produced in a electrolysis between  a aluminum cathode and a aluminum anode in a solution of magnesium sulfate.I am relatively new at chemistry and I am only in high school so I can’t figure out this precipitate. I would also like to know if there is a new dissolved salt being formed. Thanks in advance all ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnesium sulfate ionizes to Mg++ and SO4-- ions in water. When current is passed thru a solution of these ions, sulfate ion will be electrolyzed at the anode, giving O2 and SO3 which becomes H2SO4. The pH at the anode will decrease as acid is produced and attacks the aluminum. A thick layer may build up. This is the basis for anodization of aluminum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anodizing. I think any thickening of the aluminum oxide layer is quite adhesive, but some may fall off.

The cathode (negative electrode) attracts the Mg++ ions, and when they get their electrons, the magnesium atoms react with water to give H2 and Mg(OH)2. The magnesium hydroxide may stick to the cathode at first, but will eventually thicken and pieces/powder will fall off. The liquid around the cathode will become alkaline.

So the precipitate will be mostly Mg(OH)2, but there may be some aluminum oxides or hydroxides in it too.

Answer (score 0):

Aluminum is not a good idea for carrying out electrolysis, because this metal is covered by a thin layer of aluminum oxide (or alumina) that is insulating. The current passing between these electrodes must be really weak, because the resistance of this layer is high. So that you need a high tension to break this layer and make an electrolysis. But, as soon as aluminium is in contact with water, a new aluminum layer is formed. The majority of the electric energy is wasted and lost for heating the solution. This is non-sense. The powder that you get is probably aluminum oxide coming from the broken alumina layer I told you about earlier. And magnesium is not involved in this reaction.

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen a white precipitate in a galvanic cell scenario involving aluminum and magnesium sulfate.

My guess is $\ce{Mg[Al(OH)4]2}$ and not $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ which can form a problematic white suspension (not observed).

An extract from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminate):

> There are many mixed oxides containing aluminium where there are no discrete or polymeric aluminate ions. The spinels with a generic formula $\ce{A^2+B^3+_2O^2-_4}$ that contain aluminium as $\ce{Al^3+},$ such as the mineral spinel itself, $\ce{MgAl2O4}$ are mixed oxides with cubic close packed $\ce{O}$ atoms and aluminium $\ce{Al^3+}$ in octahedral positions.